# Hide a div - Why it's not working?

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

I'm trying to use [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to deal with the recent EU cookie laws.
Everything is working good, however I'd like to display different cookie "warning" messages according to different devices.

```
<div class="cookiepopup mobile_no">
        <p>Questo sito utilizza i cookie, per garantire una migliore esperienza di navigazione. Continuando, ne accetti l'utilizzo.<br /> 
        This website uses cookies to improve your user experience. By continuing to browse the site you are agreeing to our use of cookies.<br />
        <a href="/foo" target="_blank"><b>(Dettagli / Details)</b></a> <input type="submit" class="cookieclose" value="Accetto / Continue" /></p>
    </div>

    <div class="cookiepopup mobile_yes">
        <p>Questo sito utilizza i cookie. Continuando, ne accetti l'utilizzo. 
        This website uses cookies. By continuing to browse the site you are agreeing to our use of cookies.<br />
        <a href="/foo" target="_blank"><b>(Dettagli / Details)</b></a> <input type="submit" class="cookieclose" value="Accetto / Continue" /></p>
    </div>
```

In style.css:

```
.mobile_yes{ display:none } <--- normal behaviour
.mobile_no{ display:none } <---- it goes under a specific css media query for smartphones
```

Speaking in general terms and without considering the css media queries, I can't hide any of the divs. Whatever I do, `.mobile_no` div is always showed.

```
/* COOKIE POPUP */
.cookiepopup {
display:none;
background: #eee; border-top:1px solid #ddd; color:#555; 
bottom: 0;
padding: 5px 2% 10px;
position: fixed;
width: 96%;
z-index: 10; 
font-size:0.8em; 
}

.cookiepopup p {
width:90%; margin:0 auto;  max-width: 970px;
}

.mobile_no{ display:none }
```

JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    check_cookie_for_cookiepopup();

});/*ready*/

var cookiepopup_cookie_name = "cookiepopup" ;
var cookiepopup_duration = 60 ; //scadenza in giorni
var show_cookiepopup = '';

function check_cookie_for_cookiepopup()
{ 
  show_cookiepopup = $.cookie( cookiepopup_cookie_name ); 
  if (show_cookiepopup == 'noshow') {

  } else {
    setTimeout(function(){ cookiepopup_show(); },1000);
  }
}

function cookiepopup_show() {
    $('.cookiepopup').show();
    $('.cookiepopup').find('.cookieclose').unbind('click').click(function(){
        $('.cookiepopup').hide();
        show_cookiepopup = 'noshow';
        $.cookie(cookiepopup_cookie_name, show_cookiepopup, { expires: cookiepopup_duration, path: '/' });
        return false;
    });
}

function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
    lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
{
    // http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml
    var domain_string = valid_domain ?
                       ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ; 
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
                       "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
                       "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
                       24 * lifespan_in_days +
                       "; " ;

}
```

Demo at http://www.flapane.com/test/test.php

I'm sure I'm missing something. Any help would be much appreciated.
*** CODE REFRESHED *** Is it something related to `function cookiepopup_show()` ?

Comment: You can only use the ID attribute (and thus the `#` selector) on ONE tag only.

Comment: Thanks. Of course, IDs must be unique. I changed them to `<div class="cookiepopup mobile_yes">` and `<div class="cookiepopup mobile_no">` and so did I in the stylesheet. However, if you (the answer goes to all of you who answered after j08691, thanks to you, too) take a look at the DEMO page, `.mobile_no` div is still showed. I wonder if `jquery $('.cookiepopup').show()` is the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Change the id `#cookiepopup` to a class `.cookiepopup` and then your CSS rules will work properly.

At the moment, the id selector rule is more specific than your class selector rule.

As noted by others, id's should be unique in a page.

Answer (score 2):

ids should be unique. You have two divs with the same id
.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `id` and `class` the wrong way around. `id`s should be unique, `classes` don't have to be. See a (simplified) working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/zQE4g/)